# Orientdb dosen't close tcp connections

Tags: database-connection

I'm using orientdb 2.2.14 with scala. The connections aren't closed and application crashes. The following test displays the problem

```
val poolFactory = new OPartitionedDatabasePoolFactory()
poolFactory.setMaxPoolSize(40)

val pool = poolFactory.get("remote:db.test.com.br/mydb", "admin", "password")
val conn = pool.acquire()

try {
val query = StringBuilder.newBuilder

  query.append("SELECT @this.tojson(\"fetchPlan:*:-1\") AS itens FROM Parceiro limit 1000;")

 val res = conn.query[java.util.List[ODocument]](new OSQLSynchQuery[ODocument](query.toString)).asScala.toList

  val result = {
    if (res.isEmpty) {
      None
    } else {
      Some(res(0).field("itens"))
    }
  }

  result

} finally {
  conn.close()
  pool.close()
  poolFactory.close()
}
```

After execute, connection stays alive. The pool close dosen't work.

netstat -ant | fgrep 2424
tcp6 0 0 :::2424 :::* LISTEN

tcp6 0 0 172.17.0.1:51928 172.17.0.1:2424 ESTABLISHED

When I do same test with postgreSQL DB the result is:

netstat -ant | fgrep 5432
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5432 127.0.0.1:36988 TIME_WAIT

tcp6 0 0 :::5432 :::* LISTEN